# Drawing Control Flow Graphs using code

Tags: control-flow-graph

Draw the Flow Control Diagram for the following piece of code.

```
insertion_procedure (int a[], int p [], int N)
{
      int i,j,k;
      for (i=0; i<=N; i++)
      p[i] = i;
      for (i=2; i<=N; i++)
      {
            k = p[i];
            j = 1;
            while (a[p[j-1]] > a[k])
            {
                 p[j] = p[j-1];
                 j—-;
            }
              p[j] = k;
      }
}
```

Can someone show me how to draw a control flow graph as I am unfamiliar. Also if you can't help don't respond with a stupid answer. This question is relation to an exam I have coming up in Software Testing. Thank You

Comment: I’m hoping you can answer your own question by now?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913708/how-to-draw-a-control-flow-graph-from-this-code